# Recovery volume does not show up in Startup Manager

Tags: macos, partition, recovery, startup

While upgrading a MacBook Pro from OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan to macOS 10.13 High Sierra in a step-by-step procedure, I created a clone of the Recovery HD volume. Unfortunately, this newly created clone does not show up in Startup Manager's selection list. Details see *Problem* section below.

### Hardware-Software-Environment

MacBook Pro Early 2015 running OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan.
The internal HD is actually a 250 GB SSD comprising partitions `EFI`,                    `Macintosh HD` and `Recovery HD`. There is no encryption enabled on any of these partitions.
External 2 TB HD connected via USB 3.0 Bus; later on called target disk.

### Task

Create a bootable clone of the `Recovery HD`partition on the target disk. Provide a robust and *simple command line based* procedure. Wherever possible, avoid fiddeling around with the GPT entries.

### Solution Attempt

1. Apply `diskutil resizeVolume` to create a new 1.0 GB partition on the
   target disk carrying a JHFS+ file system. To prevent subsequent naming
   confusion we 'baptize' the newly created partition to `Recovery HD` so
   that the name of the partition and the corresponding GPT label will agree.
2. Run `asr restore` to 'populate' the new recovery partition.

   ```
   asr restore --source /dev/disk0s3 --target /dev/disk2s9 --erase
   ```

   where, in this case, disk0s3 is the disk id of the recovery partition which is
   associated to the startup volume while disk2s9 is the disk id of the 'new'
   recovery partition on the target disk.
3. Run `asr adjust` to set the appropriate type to the 'new' recovery partition

   ```
   asr adjust --target /dev/disk2s9 --settype "Apple_Boot"
   ```
4. `diskutil info` output for the 'new' recovery partition:

   ```
   Device Identifier:        disk2s9
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2s9
   Whole:                    No
   Part of Whole:            disk2
   Device / Media Name:      Recovery HD

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

   File System:              None

   Partition Type:           Apple_Boot
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              AA10BAA6-C29B-37A6-BA1C-0EACCFD304C9
   Disk / Partition UUID:    2B1B46B7-8068-493F-A8CC-475EFECD89EA

   Total Size:               1000.0 MB (999997440 Bytes) (exactly 1953120 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:          External
   Removable Media:          No
   ```

   `gpt -vvv  show -l /dev/disk2` output (snippet):

   ```
   gpt show: /dev/disk2: mediasize=2000365289472; sectorsize=512; blocks=3906963456
   gpt show: /dev/disk2: PMBR at sector 0
   gpt show: /dev/disk2: Pri GPT at sector 1
   ...
   gpt show: /dev/disk2: GPT partition: type=426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC, start=1331274184, size=1953120
   ...
   gpt show: /dev/disk2: Sec GPT at sector 3906963455
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
    ...
   1331274184     1953120      9  GPT part - "Recovery HD"
    ...
   3906701272      262151         
   3906963423          32         Sec GPT table
   3906963455           1         Sec GPT header
   ```

### Problem

With the external HD connected, invoke the Startup Manager holding down the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key on starting or restarting the machine.

The Startup Manager does not show the newly created recovery partition in the list of volume icons representing those partitions it considers bootable.

**Question:** What is wrong with the above solution attempt trying to create a bootable recovery partition? Any advices and suggestions are welcome.

**Additional question:** Can it be that this issue is induced by a side effect of the System Integrity Protection feature that has been introduced in El Capitan? See item #4 in the *Sources and Footnotes* section below.

### Observations and Tests

1. *Observation*: We start from a properly created clone of the built-in startup volume, thus it consists of a `Macintosh HD` and a `Recovery HD`partition, hereafter invoke the Startup Manager, the clone now appears as a (single) icon labelled `Macintosh HD`.

   If we rename solely the `Macintosh HD` to, say, `macintosh_hd_10_11_6_yymmdd` the clone appears as a pair of icons labelled `macintosh_hd_10_11_6_yymmdd` and `Macintosh HD`, where the latter denotes the *recovery partition*.

   If we rename both, the`Macintosh HD` and the `Recovery HD` to, say, `macintosh_hd_10_11_6_yymmdd` resp. `recovery_hd_10_11_2_yymmdd` the clone appears as a (single) icon labelled `macintosh_hd_10_11_6_yymmdd`.
2. *Observation*: Again starting from a properly created clone of the built-in startup volume, we 'purge' the `Macintosh HD` via `diskutil reformat` while leaving the `Recovery HD` untouched. Now, the Startup Manager does not show the 'left-over' recovery partition; before, the clone of the built-in startup volume appeared as an icon labelled `Macintosh HD` as described above.
3. *Tests*: It doesn't achieve anything ..
   .. if we carry out the above processing steps in Recovery Mode.
   .. if we modify the above processing steps in so far that we start from another (working)                `Recovery HD` partition clone instead of the one associated to the current, built-in startup  volume.
   .. if we modify the above processing steps in so far that we, at first, create a disk image
   of the `Recovery HD` partition and subsequently run `asr restore` taking this disk
   image as source.
4. *Test*: Before executing step #2 of the above processing steps we
   disable SIP. (Run `csrutil disable` in Recovery Mode; don't miss 
   to re-enable SIP when you're done!)

   Disappointingly this did'nt fix the issue.

### Sources and Footnotes

[Changing a Volume's "Device / Media Name"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23373/changing-a-volumes-device-media-name/143579#143579)
Discussing the relationship between partition name and label resp. volume and device/media name.

[Recovery HD Is not showing up. Is it because of FileVault?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180043/recovery-hd-is-not-showing-up-is-it-because-of-filevault)
Contains an insightful discussion about the Startup Manager's label trickery.

https://bombich.com/de/kb/ccc5/frequently-asked-questions-about-cloning-apples-recovery-hd-partition
A very useful text from the Bombich Software knowledge base introducing the term of an *operational Recovery HD*.

https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/macos-recovery-partition-without-reinstalling-macos/
Presents the Recovery Partition Creator tool; mentions that System Integrity Protection (SIP) needs to be disabled in order to clone the recovery partition in El Capitan.

Comment: @klanomath Do you see a chance to get this question answered?